# The climate effect of the Russian industrial collapse in the early 90's

Tags: climate-change, greenhouse-gases, fossil-fuel, predictability

In 1982 ExxonMobil made this diagram with a slightly excess of the concentration of atmospheric carbon dioxide and global warming. Can this error be explained by the Russian industrial collapse in the 90's, when their oil and coal production was very low for some years?

[Source: The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/climate-consensus-97-per-cent/2018/sep/19/shell-and-exxons-secret-1980s-climate-change-warnings)

[image]

[image]